# Cannot create objects in Runnable's run method

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable, lombok

I have created a class that implements runnable and in its run method I want to multithread rest-assured requests. I created a model class for the post body of these requests that implements the lombok builder. Here is the code in the run class:

```
    public void run() {
        try {
            System.out.println("In run");
            RequestSpecification requestSpecification = new RequestSpecBuilder()
                    .setRelaxedHTTPSValidation()
                    .addFilters(Arrays.asList(new RequestLoggingFilter()))
                    .setBaseUri(BASE_URL)
                    .build();
            System.out.println("Request spec Created");
            DataModel dataModel = DataModel.builder().build();
            System.out.println("Data Model Created");
            given()
                    .spec(requestSpecification)
                    .basePath(BASE_PATH)
                    .when()
                    .body(dataModel)
                    .post();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I found that the requests were not getting sent and upon further investigation I found that the run ceased on the request body object creation (see above).

Here is the output:

```
About to enter run
About to enter run
In run
About to enter run
In run
About to enter run
In run
About to enter run
In run
About to enter run
In run
About to enter run
In run
About to enter run
In run
Request spec Created
Request spec Created
In run
Request spec Created
Request spec Created
Request spec Created
Request spec Created
Request spec Created
Request spec Created
```

Is there some reason why I can't build an object here?

A

Just to be clear I'm saying that the run method seems to stop on

```
DataModel dataModel = DataModel.builder().build();
```

as the next print statement is not run. It is also notable that an exception is never thrown so it seems to just stop there dead in its tracks

Comment: according to the output you show, it doesn't stop at the creation of that Request, since it prints the 'Request spec Created' line.

Comment: the run ceased on the request body object creation. so the request spec was created but the the request body object wasn't (DataModel dataModel = DataModel.builder().build();). That is the body object used in the actual request further on in the method

Comment: yes, but it is obvious you CAN (and have) built an object there. With what you've shown alone, I have no idea what might be the issue

Comment: I switched in around to have the DataModel built before the request spec along with the accompanying print statement and it appears then that I only get "In run" print statements. The difference between the RequestSpecification object and the DataModel object is lombok. Could that be the issue?

Comment: "the difference is lombok", what is that supposed to mean? You show no relevant code to show the differences, you show no logs ... what exactly do you expect us to say?